# how to remove unwanted items from gnome "Other menu"  

Tags: menu, gnome-classic

I opened `Other` menu and found that it contains a lot of items (see image)
Is there a way to clean-it up? Don't want to edit menu manually...

[image: mess menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`System Tools`** >> **`Preferences`** >> **`Main Menu`** and Deselect the Ones you don't want to view in **`Other Menu`** as

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good solution. Menu was OK some time ago, and then something happened - I want to understand what happened.